# I can't access to route params, ngrx

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, ngrx, subscribe

Hello I have routing like this:

```
path: ':paramA/:paramB',
component: MyComponent
```

I can't access to route params by subscribing, it don't recognize any changes in route params. It is possible to get access by router state, but I don't want to. I am using detection strategy onPush.

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: I had activated route subscription in app component which has router outlet inside. I have only access to activatedroute from components displayed in router outlet.